# Find the frequency of a set of values in multiple data frames in r

Tags: r, for-loop, count, frequency

I would like to find the frequency of each row of a data frame in other multiple data frames. In other words, i have to find out how many times each two values in a row can be seen in other files

I have 103 files. If read them as a data frame, they will be like:

```
    V1   V2
    1    xbc
    1    xbd
    1    xbf
    2    xbr
    2    xbt
    3    xbu
    3    xbi
    3    xbo
```

(V2 is not numeric). I have to find out how many times each row in a file can be seen in other 102 files!

I try a nested for loop. but it is damn slow! because each file has at least 4500 rows!

```
    for(j in 1:nrow(df1)){
       df1<- df1[j,]   #select just one row of the data frame each time to find its frequency!

       setwd("my path")
       file<-list.files(pattern="^inp")

       for (i in file) {
       df<-read.table(i)
       mylist<-list()
       tmp <- merge(df1,df, c("V1", "V3"))
       mylist[[i]] <- tmp #put all vectors in the list
      }
     df <- do.call("rbind",mylist) #combine all vectors into a matrix

     k<-toString(j) #to avoid connection error in write.table
     setwd("my path")
     write.table(x, file=k, append=FALSE, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

}

I would appreciate it if anyone can suggest me any other faster ways?

Comment: The idea of using `merge` is good, but why do you do it for each row seperately? I'd merge the whole data.frames and count duplicates (using `duplicated`). Also, data.table joins should be faster than base R's `merge`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. Let me check your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I did the merge of the whole data frames. It is much faster but the problem is now, how can i get the frequency of a record in the resulted merge file!? when i separate each row, then, by counting the resulted file's row number, i could get the frequency count!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little example. `dat2` is just `dat1` with three values changed to show that we are finding them to be different from those in `dat1`.

```
> dat1 <- read.table(h=T, text = "V1   V2
  1    xbc
  1    xbd
  1    xbf
  2    xbr
  2    xbt
  3    xbu
  3    xbi
  3    xbo")
> dat2 <- dat1
> dat2[c(2, 4, 5),1] <- 0
```

You could iterate through the second data frame, using `%in%` with `all` to determine if the entire row is match. This returns a logical vector, which we sum to get the number of rows in `dat2` that are also in `dat1`.

```
> sap <- sapply(seq(nrow(dat1)), function(i){
      all(dat2[i, ] %in% dat1[i, ])
  }))
> sum(sap)
# [1] 5
```

As noted in the comments, we can `rbind` all the data together and then just use `duplicated` to get the result.

```
> d <- do.call(rbind, list(dat1, dat2))
> sum(duplicated(d))
[1] 5
```

Answer (score -1):

It could be done in two steps.

1. Make statistic about each file. Statistic about frequency each line in 102 files. Result is smaller then original file and have information what you need.
2. Second step is similar your code, but you can save statistic to memory and you can break the searching in case of first occurence.

It should be 2times faster (without statistic in memory). But it depend on data.
Also you can sort the statistic and use benefits of [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Comment: Thanks, but actually, i don't know how to implement your suggestion in codes!